# No TX / RX information on bond interface

Tags: networking, network-interface, bonding

I create a bond interface with two members, eth1 and eth2.

```
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: load balancing (round-robin)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 100
Down Delay (ms): 200

Slave Interface: eth1
MII Status: up
Speed: Unknown
Duplex: Unknown
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 92:90:2c:3b:d8:c0
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eth2
MII Status: up
Speed: Unknown
Duplex: Unknown
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 8e:0a:9a:12:ac:e9
Slave queue ID: 0

3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 92:90:2c:3b:d8:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 92:90:2c:3b:d8:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 92:90:2c:3b:d8:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.60.155/24 brd 192.168.60.255 scope global bond0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The bond interface seams working correcty because i can ping the assigned IP.
C:\Users\andre>ping -t 192.168.60.155

```
Pinging 192.168.60.155 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.60.155: bytes=32 time=38ms TTL=63
Reply from 192.168.60.155: bytes=32 time=38ms TTL=63
Reply from 192.168.60.155: bytes=32 time=40ms TTL=63
```

The main problem is that i can't get the correct RX / TX information from the bond, seams that the values is not refreshing.

```
root@proxy01:~# ip -s -s link show dev bond0
5: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 92:90:2c:3b:d8:c0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    848        8        0       0       0       0
    RX errors: length   crc     frame   fifo    missed
               0        0       0       0       0
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    0          0        0       0       0       0
    TX errors: aborted  fifo   window heartbeat transns
               0        0       0       0       2

root@proxy01:~# cat /proc/net/dev
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
  eth0:  253789    1724    0    0    0     0          0         0   189425    1684    0    0    0     0       0          0
 bond0:     848       8    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
  eth2:     424       4    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
  tun0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
  eth1:     424       4    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
    lo: 3875872    6945    0    0    0     0          0         0  3875872    6945    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

I only get the initial values when the bond initializes (RX:848 TX:0), but then is not refreshing with the usage.

Anyone can help me to undersantd this issue?
I'm using debian 10 with kernel 4.19.0-20-amd64

Comment: FWIW I can't reproduce this on latest kernel (6.5) using namespaces and veth interfaces (bond0 more or less adds the values of eth1 and eth2). Could this be a problem that was fixed in previous kernels or a driver problem?